# Track Facebook post

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-wall

Can is it possible to track users particular wall post and the no of like counts he get for that particular wall post?

I am developing the game where, user post the status from android applications and will be rewarded for no.of likes he get for that status.

Comment: Did you have a look at the facebook API?

Comment: yes, but as per my information, we can track the users wall status,but for tracking the particular wall post, i have no idea, i tried the graph api explore to test the post,but every time user changes the status, got the latest status updated by user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is what you can do:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[UID]/feed?access_token=[accessToken]
```

This will return a json response which you can parse and find the correct status and you can then count the likes of that status. It's probably not the best way to do it, but I hope it will push you in the right direction. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/542999741/feed?access_token=2227470867|2.AQAkVvIHnBGhG52S.3600.1313748000.0-542999741|wdVFlndfUqaBIf3hcDWW7-18Xx4

That is my feed